# Javascript_include_tags not showing anything on page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app and All of the javascript is page specific, so I can't do

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I have the following code on one page:

```
apple

<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery_ujs_sub.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.c2selectbox.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/functions_sub.js" %>

orange
```

but all that shows up on the page is:

```
apple


orange
```

Why isn't the javascript appearing?  I have been doing something like this for all the pages on my site.  I have not had a problem until this page, yet nothing is actually different about this page.  All of the pages are rendered via ajax, but that should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag), they should be used in this way:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery-1.8.3.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/jquery_ujs_sub" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.jscrollpane.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.c2selectbox" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/jquery.colorbox-min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/temp_js/functions_sub" %>
```

On a side note, you're suppose to include all your third-party assets under `vendor/assets`. And to deal with page specific javascripts, you should follow the Rails guide on [controller-specific-assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets).